# Buscar una cadena en una consulta a la base de datos

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy tratando de realizar un buscador para una web, pero necesito buscar palabras concretas en ese buscador, como por ejemplo "portatil i5".

He probado con `LIKE` pero no lo hace bien. Tengo que decir que a lo mejor esa cadena que busco no está al principio ni al final, si no que está contenida.

He probado esta función de MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM comparador WHERE MATCH (titulo) AGAINST ('+"portatil i5"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

No me devuelve nada, pero si pongo un 14, sí lo hace bien.

Y también esta otra:

```
SELECT * FROM comparador WHERE MATCH (titulo) AGAINST ('+portatil +i5' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

La que devuelve unos resultados similares es la primera, pero al poner `i5` se fastidia la consulta.

Luego, a parte, esto viaja desde un post con ajax.

**EDICIÓN**

*Registros en la bd de Ejemplo*

```
(34528, 0, '', '', 0, '', '', 0, 0, '', '', 0, '', 'PORTATIL ASUS X509JA-BR491T i3-1005G1 15.6HD 8GB 512SSD W10 COLOR PLATA', '', '', '', '', '90NB0QE1-M10120', 'DESYMAN', '', 369, 0, '0', '', 0, 'https://desyman.com/articulos/artporta asus x509ja-br491t_1.jpg\r', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '2020-10-08 07:10:40'),
    (34529, 0, '', '', 0, '', '', 0, 0, '', '', 0, '', 'PORTATIL ASUS X509JA-BR252T i3-1005G1 15.6HD 8GB 256SSD W10 COLOR PLATA', '', '', '', '', '90NB0QE1-M09760', 'DESYMAN', '', 339, 0, '0', '', 0, 'https://desyman.com/articulos/artporta asus x509ja-br252t_1.jpg\r', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '2020-10-08 07:10:40'),
```

*Tabla en la BD*

```
CREATE TABLE `comparador` (


`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_categoria` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `categoria` text COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `ruta_categoria` text COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `id_subcategoria` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subcategoria` text COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `marca` text COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `id_marca` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_proveedor` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tipo` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `ruta` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `estado` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `url_producto` text COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `titulo` text COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `titular` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `descripcion` text COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `youtube` text COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `multimedia` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `codigo` text COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `proveedor` text COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `ean` text COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `costo` float NOT NULL,
  `canon` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `stock` text COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `detalles` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `precio` float NOT NULL,
  `portada` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `vistas` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ventas` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `vistasGratis` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ventasGratis` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ofertadoPorCategoria` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ofertadoPorSubCategoria` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `oferta` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `precioOferta` float NOT NULL,
  `descuentoOferta` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `imgOferta` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `finOferta` datetime NOT NULL,
  `peso` float NOT NULL,
  `entrega` float NOT NULL,
  `fecha` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish2_ci;
```

**Código php de la aplicación**

```
// Incluimos nuestro archivo CONEXION
require_once "../app/conexion.php";

$articuloAbuscar = $_POST["articulo"];


$articulo = DB::queryExecute("SELECT * 
                                FROM comparador
                                WHERE MATCH (titulo)
                                AGAINST ('".$articuloAbuscar."' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
                                LIMIT 50;
                            ");



echo "<div class='row'>";
    for($i=0; $i<count($articulo); $i++){

        echo "<div class='col-md-2'>";

            if($articulo[$i]["portada"] != null){
                echo "<img class='imagenProducto' src='".$articulo[$i]['portada']."'/>" . "<br/>";
            }else{
                echo "No tiene imagen" ."<br/>" ;
            }

            $id = $articulo[$i]['id'];

            echo "<br/>";
            echo "<span> Titulo: ".$articulo[$i]["titulo"] ."</span>". "<br/>";
            echo "<span> Proveedor: ".$articulo[$i]["proveedor"] ."</span>". "<br/>";
            echo "<span> PN: " . $articulo[$i]["codigo"] . "</span>" . "<br/><br/>";
            echo "<span class='bg-danger text-white'> Costo: " . $articulo[$i]["costo"] . "</span>" . "<br/><br/>";
            echo "<span class='bg-danger text-white'> Stock: " . $articulo[$i]["stock"] . "</span>" . "<br/><br/>";
            echo "<a href='controladores/generarOfertaEmseel.php?id=$id'>
                    <button class='btn btn-success mb-5'>Crear Oferta EMSEEL</button>
                  </a>";
            echo "<a href='controladores/generarOfertaIntegra.php?id=$id'>
                    <button class='btn btn-success mb-5'>Crear Oferta Informatica</button>
                  </a>";
            
        echo "</div>";
    }
echo "</div>";

json_encode($articulo);
```

*Class conexion*

```
class DB {


public static function connect() {
    try{
        $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=10.48.0.19;dbname=bbdd-tienda-integra","root","pass");
        $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "Error: ". $e->getMessage();
    }

return $connection;
}


// EXECUTE QUERY MYSQL TYPE SELECT
public static function queryExecute($sql){
    $arrayData = array();

    try{

        $connection = DB::connect();

        $stmt = $connection->query($sql);
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $stmt->execute();

        // SAVE THE DATA IN ARRAY
        $arrayData = $stmt->fetchAll();


    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo 'Error: '. $e->getMessage();
    }
return $arrayData;
}
```

*consulta INDEX*

```
//generamos la consulta
$resultado = DB::queryExecute("SELECT DISTINCT id, titulo, codigo, proveedor, costo, stock, portada FROM comparador ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10");
```

Tengo que decir, que es una aplicación realizada con php puro, nada de MVC, y solo la estoy modificando, no la he realizado yo y me estoy volviendo loco con muchas cosas....

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Si quieres usar `AGAINST` debes activar la búsqueda de texto completo en esos campos: [documentación oficial de MySQL sobre búsqueda de texto completo](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html). ¿Están correctamente configurados los campos para que se pueda usar `AGAINST` en ellos o no lo has hecho?

Comment: Presupongo que esa parte ya la tienes bien aunque no hayas respondido, por lo que te sugiero que compartas el contenido de tus registros o, al menos, los que piensas que deberían aparecer en la búsqueda. Por lo pronto te he explicado el motivo por el que puede que no recibas ningún resultado en la primera y que la segunda no funcione como esperas.

Comment: Hola @OscarGarcia gracias por tu respuesta. efectivamente, ya tengo como fulltext mi campo titulo en la BD. He realizado lo que el compañero de la respuesta de abajo ha dicho y no funciona. Voy a tratar de compartir algunos datos, para que así se pueda comprobar

Comment: El compañero de la respuesta de abajo soy yo :) también vendría bien saber cómo montas la consulta SQL desde PHP (de paso comprobamos que no sea sensible a inyección SQL). Quedo a la espera de más datos para poder seguir echando una mano.

Comment: Gracias @OscarGarcia creo que no me dejo nada de info que me has solicitado. Cualquier cosa me avisas. Yo quiero poner en el buscador portatil i5, en los ejemplos he puesto i3, y que aparezcan esos datos, todos ya luego yo cogeré lo que necesite

Comment: ¿Qué es `DB::queryExecute`? ¿Usas PDO o mysqli? Lo digo porque, por desgracia, tu código sufre de inyección SQL.

Comment: es PDO. Te adjunto, mi class conexión. De todas formas es una aplicación de uso interno, no está en un hosting ni nada

Comment: He agregado más información en mi respuesta que debería ayudarte con tu problema. La primera parte soluciona los [graves problemas de seguridad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) asociados a la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyección_SQL). Por favor, usa siempre consultas preparadas o escapa correctamente las cadenas que agregues a código SQL. La segunda parte te ayudará a que se incluya en el índice de búsquedas de texto completo los términos que tengan un único carácter, para que términos cortos como `i5` puedan ser usados en las búsquedas.

Comment: muchas gracias @OscarGarcia, pero tu código, al pasarle un segundo parámetro, me destroza mi listado la cual hago en mi edición nuevamente, que es la que me carga algunos artículos en mi index

Comment: de verdad @OscarGarcia te agradezco toda la ayuda proporcionada y los consejos que usaré de aquí en adelante, estoy acostumbrado a trabajar más con MVC sobre todo Laravel, con PDO directamente no tengo tanta experiencia

Comment: Mi código debería ser transparente para llamadas sin parámetros. Si no se indica el parámetro obtendrá el valor `null` que, a su vez, al ser pasado a `execute(null)` asumirá que no hay ningún marcador.

Comment: Por favor, para no alargar la conversación a base de comentarios, [continuemos el intercambio de información en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113870/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-scorpions).

Comment: @OscarGarcia pero me devuelve el siguiente error en el index: Error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Comment: Por favor, hablemos por el chat. El enlace está en el comentario anterior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Con la información nueva que proporcionas puedo ayudarte mejor.

Para empezar, deberías proteger tu código de los [graves problemas de seguridad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) asociados a la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL) que debe solucionarse con consultas preparadas o bien usando [`PDO::quote()`](https://php.net/es/pdo.quote).

Como estableces una conexión por cada consulta SQL (algo que no te recomiendo y que es malísimo en cuestión a rendimiento), lo más sencillo es preparar tu función para recibir los valores de los marcadores para hacer uso de una consulta preparada:

```
$articulo = DB::queryExecute("
    SELECT * 
    FROM comparador
    WHERE
      MATCH (titulo) AGAINST (:articulo IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
    LIMIT 50;
", [
    ':articulo' => $_POST["articulo"]
]);
```

La implementación del método de tu clase cambiaría a:

```
class DB {
    /* ... */

    public static function queryExecute($sql, $marcadores = []) {
        try {
            $connection = DB::connect();
            /* No hacemos la consulta, solo la preparamos */
            $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            /* Ejecutamos la consulta usando los marcadores proporcionados */
            $stmt->execute($marcadores);
            /* Devolvemos el resultado, no es necesario almacenarlo */
            return $stmt->fetchAll();
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            /* Finalizamos la ejecución del script */
            die(htmlspecialchars('Error: '. $e->getMessage()));
        }
    }
}
```

Por otro lado estoy viendo que tu PHP genera HTML y luego parece intentar devolver un JSON con `json_encode($articulo);`, pero obviamente eso último no funcionará sin una función de salida al navegador (como `echo`).

---

Problemas que sufres con tus dos búsquedas:

- `+"portatil i5"`: Las comillas se usan para buscar exactitud en la secuencia de términos. Estás buscando el término `portátil` seguido inmediatamente después por el término `i5`. Si no existe ningún registro que tenga ambas palabras inmediatamente una después de la otra entonces no te aparecerá ningún resultado.
- `+portatil +i5`: El símbolo `+` indica que debe encontrarse esa palabra y el `-` que no debería estar. Ten en cuenta que el término `i5` [no llega a la longitud mínima por defecto (3 caracteres)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_ft_min_token_size) para que pueda ser indexado, por lo que la consulta lo ignorará por completo.

Para solucionar esto último necesitarás cambiar la configuración del servidor MySQL de manera permanente y reconstruir el índice de búsqueda de texto completo de la manera que expongo a continuación.

### Configuración del servidor MySQL

Para modificar el tamaño mínimo de los términos que se agregarán al índice de texto completo hay que agregar las siguientes líneas al apartado `[mysqld]` del archivo de configuración del servidor MySQL (suele ser `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`):

```
[mysqld]
innodb_ft_min_token_size=1
ft_min_word_len=1
```

Reiniciar el servidor MySQL para que surtan efecto los cambios.

### Reconstrucción del índice de búsqueda de texto completo

Ahora deberemos reconstruir el índice de búsqueda de texto completo para que incluya los nuevos términos mediante la siguiente consulta SQL:

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE comparador
```

A partir de ahora podrás usar el término `i5` en una búsqueda pare delimitar los resultados obtenidos.

Puedes ver la respuesta original [en este enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/395516/3).

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Como podría entonces realizar la consulta del buscador para que admita una búsqueda de ese tipo¿?? porque efectivamente, como has puesto en el ejemplo en vivo, he probado y me muestran otros resultados, pero no los portátiles con i5

Comment: ¿Quieres que el término `i5` se incluya en las búsquedas? Si es así debo indicarte los pasos para cambiar la configuración de manera permanente y, además, reconstruir el índice de búsqueda.

Comment: si, claro, quiero que se pueda poner i3 i5 i7, o lo que sea... Igual que si ponemos en google pepe, que aparece todo lo relacionado con pepe, quizás el ejemplo es un poco malo, pero no se si me entiendes, es una buscador de productos que debería de admitir cualquier cosa